# Hyperref Warnings

Tags: hyperref, warnings

Overleaf tells me this:

[image: Yperref Warnings]

Why? Thank you so much

**First Edit:** (Reading comment) A short tex-code from Overleaf and just edited by me:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Welcome to Overleaf --- just edit your LaTeX on the left,
% and we'll compile it for you on the right. If you open the
% 'Share' menu, you can invite other users to edit at the same
% time. See www.overleaf.com/learn for more info. Enjoy!
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Example of Hyperlinks}
\author{Overleaf}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
{\huge {\bf Foreword}}

\Blindtext
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dummy entry\quad quad}
{\huge {\bf Dummy entry}}

\Blindtext
\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter, $a=b$}

This will be an empty chapter

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i
\end{equation}

The equation \ref{eq:1} shows a sum that is divergent. This formula will be used later on page \pageref{second}.

\Blindtext
\clearpage

\section{Second section} \label{second}

\blindtext
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have section titles containing 'special' symbols? I think I had this problem once when I used `\,` in a section title. I think PDFs aren't able to handle this special symbol. Try to find out what causes this problem, and then use `\texorpdfstring`. Note: Maybe I am completely wrong.

Comment: What do you mean whit specila symbol? I'm writing a treatise of Algebra. And I added several things like \newcommand{}{} and \newcommand{}[]{}. Could this be the problem?

Comment: A think like `\section{$x^2$}` can cause similar warnings as it cannot convert `$x^2$` to something that the bookmarks can understand. Thus use use `\texofpdfstring{for text}{for bookmarks}` to help it. Without showing us more about what is triggering this, we cannot help much. Exactly what do you have that causes `\hskip 14.4pt`?

Comment: I don't think so. It would be a lot easier if you could provide an MWE. As I said, in my case it was a thin space (`\,`) which caused a problem sounding similar to yours

Comment: the first warning means that you aren't using headings in the right order, you have e.g. somewhere a \section followed by a \paragraph. The second means that you have in a heading or caption a space command like \quad, the third that you have math. For both you can use something like  `\texorpdfstring{$a=b$}{version for bookmarks e.g. a=b}`  to help hyperref.

Comment: Please, can you add a full minimal compilable code? I like the orange but the size of the characters are very tiny :-(

Comment: Please, consider that `\bf` and the similar commands have been deprecated for almost 30 years.

Comment: Thanks, already known. However I use Ctrl B in order to have \textbf{text in bold}. But No one has answered my question. The problem is not serious but I'd like to solv it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your code does not create similar errors like you posted, at least in my environment. It may be because you did not use `hyperref` at all ind the code snippet.

If I go through each warning I've got and "cure" it, I end up with this one, taking some comments made into account:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Example of Hyperlinks}
\author{Overleaf}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
{\huge {\bf Foreword}}

\Blindtext
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dummy entry}% <<==
{\huge {\bf Dummy entry}}

\Blindtext
\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter, equality}% <<==

This will be an empty chapter

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i
\end{equation}

The equation \ref{eq:1} shows a sum that is divergent. This formula will be used later on page \pageref{second}.
\Blindtext
\clearpage

\section{Second section} \label{second}

\blindtext
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

**Screenshot**:

[image: Screenshot]

To localize the source of your warnings I suggest a "homing-in" strategy. I.e. delete one half of your relevant text, rund + check, restore, delete other half, run + check. If you do it right, i.e. matching your situation, one half should pass, while the other will fail. Repeat. // Consider "halfness" as a fuzzy concept. It can be really 50 %, or more, or less. Because you follow a $2^n$ scheme, you should quickly arrive at the trouble-makers.